# Unexpected RegexStringValidator failure in ConfigurationProperty in custom ConfigurationElement

Tags: c#, regex, configuration

I am writing my own custom configuration section and have a ConfigurationProperty defined in a ConfigurationElement like so:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("startTime", IsRequired = false)]
[RegexStringValidator("\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}")]
public string StartTime
{
    get
    {
        return (string) this["startTime"];
    }

    set
    {
        this["startTime"] = value;
    }
}
```

I am expecting to be able to enter values such as "23:30:00" in the startTime attribute of the ConfigurationElement that I have created.  However, whenever I try to load my configuration section, I get an ConfigurationErrorsException with the message:

> The value for the property 'startTime' is not valid. The error is: The value does not conform to the validation regex string '\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}'.

I'll admit I always struggle with regular expressions, but this one is simple enough and I wrote a test to verify that my pattern should validate the kinds of values I am expecting:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
var isSuccess = regex.Match("23:30:00").Success;
```

isSuccess evaluates to True, so I am not quite sure why the ConfigurationErrorsException is being thrown.

As a reference, here is my configuration section from my App.config file:

```
<windowsServiceConfiguration>
  <schedule startTime = "23:00:00" />
</windowsServiceConfiguration>
```

Any help as to why I can't get the RegexStringValidator to work would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I seem to be having a problem with validators in general.  I'm having a similar problem with the TimeSpanValidator.  I decorate a property and set a range.  The value in the config file is definitely within the range and I get an exception saying that my value is out of range.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to define the default value that will pass the validation:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("startTime", IsRequired = false, DefaultValue = "00:00:00")]
[RegexStringValidator(@"\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}")]
public string StartTime
{
    get 
    {
        return (string) this["startTime"];
    }

    set
    {
        this["startTime"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Your suggestion definitely made all of the validations work.

Comment: +1 - Let me just add that even if you've already defined a (working) default on a ConfigurationProperty, you STILL need to define one on the ConfigurationPropertyAttribute. (But the inverse is not true)

Comment: Thanks for the help, had the exact same problem and adding a default value fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the indirection from the property requires a double-escaping of the contents.  If yes, then instead of:

```
"\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}"
```

use:

```
@"\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}"
```

Ordinarly I would think that is too much, but give it a try.

Comment: That is too much.  The pattern, "\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}", is equivalent to @"\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}".  Thanks for the suggestion, though.