# Validation in Custom web config section class

Tags: asp.net, regex, web-config

I have a custom web config class. I want to add RegexStringValidator as an attribute to a web config property like:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("siteDomainName", DefaultValue = "")]
        [RegexStringValidator(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)+):?([0-9]+)?/?")]
        public string SiteDomainName
        {
            get
            {
                return (string) this["siteDomainName"];
            }
            set 
            { 
                this["siteDomainName"] = value;
            }
        }
```

The error i am getting is :

> The value does not conform to the validation regex string
>   '^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)+):?([0-9]+)?/?'.

Even if the value supplied is correct and matches the Regex.
What is the problem with this??

Comment: Maybe because the "DefaultValue" is not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like ronen said in his comment, your default value should also match the regular expression. See this answer for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5313223/4830. The reason is that the default value is also evaluated **and** validated, even when you set a value in your web.config file.

Something like this should work (default value validates, and property is required so it should never actually use the default value in practice):

```
[ConfigurationProperty("siteDomainName", DefaultValue="www.example.com", IsRequired=True)]
[RegexStringValidator(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)+):?([0-9]+)?/?")]
public string SiteDomainName
...
```

In case you don't want a default value, you could change the regular expression to accept the empty string, by making the whole value basically optional:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("siteDomainName", IsRequired=False)]
[RegexStringValidator(@"^(([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)+):?([0-9]+)?/?)?$")]
public string SiteDomainName
...
```

Notice that the use of `IsRequired` in both code examples, use the one that best fits your needs. Be aware that de default value is always going to be validated.

Comment: But I don't want to give any default value, in that case??