# Regex for semicolon separated numbers string in ConfigurationSectionDesigner validation?

Tags: c#, regex, configurationsection

Need to apply Regex validation for a string with semicolon separated HTTP status codes:

```
"202;500;503"
```

I tried this regex

```
^([0-9]+;)*[0-9]+$
```

but i get an exception:

The value for the property 'retryStatusCodes' is not valid. The error is: The value does not conform to the validation regex string `^([0-9]+;)*[0-9]+$`.

How is that possible? I tested it here: https://regexr.com/

and it worked

Why it doesnt work in C# code?

I use it for validation of attrtibutes in ConfigurationSectionDesigner, auto-generated code for this attribute:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the RetryStatusCodes.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("ConfigurationSectionDesigner.CsdFileGenerator", "2.0.3.2")]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute("The RetryStatusCodes.")]
    [global::System.Configuration.RegexStringValidatorAttribute("^([0-9]+;)*[0-9]+$")]
    [global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationPropertyAttribute(global::XXX.XXX.XXX.RetryStatusCodesPropertyName, IsRequired=true, IsKey=false, IsDefaultCollection=false)]
    public virtual string RetryStatusCodes
    {
        get
        {
            return ((string)(base[global::XXX.XXX.XXX.RetryStatusCodesPropertyName]));
        }
        set
        {
            base[global::XXX.XXX.XXX.RetryStatusCodesPropertyName] = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: it is because you validate javascript on https://regexr.com/

Comment: Well, it is not a problem to test such a simple regex at regexr.com. It works the same in JS and C#. Please check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149398/unexpected-regexstringvalidator-failure-in-configurationproperty-in-custom-confi) where a similar issue is discussed (also, a simple regex and the same exception).